# Twig.js render .twig to a file

Tags: node.js, express, twig

I would like to render a twig template, and save the html into a file. I was looking into the twig.js documentation and I couldn't find any information about it.

**Ticket**

```
twig    = require('twig');
...
  _prevTicket = function(req, res){
    var el = twig.twig({ data: 'test.twig' }).render({ test: 'pepe' });

    console.log(el);

    res.render('test.twig', { test: 'pepe' });
  };

app.get('/ticket/', _prevTicket);
```

When I access to that route I got the next message in the terminal. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks you.

**Terminal**

```
test.twig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
app.render('test.twig', { test: 'pepe' }, function(err, html){ 
    return console.log((err) ? err : html);
});
```